# Efficient way to fetch list size

Tags: spring, database, hibernate, jpa, optimization

I have an entity like below. When I need to list comment size of company I'm calling totalComments() method. For this does hibernate go to the database and fetch entire comment data or just querying with count(*)? If hibernate fetch entire comment what is the efficient way for getting comment size?

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "companies")
public class Company extends ItemEntity {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="companies_comments",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="company_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="comment_id"))
    private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<>();

    public void addComment(Comment comment) {
        this.comments.add(comment);
    }

    public int totalComments() {
        return this.comments.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. If we don't adjust for getting collection size of entity hibernate loads every comment. We can solve this performance issue in two ways.

We can use `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)` like below. By `LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA` `.size()` and `.contains()` won't initialize the whole collection.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
@JoinTable(name="companies_comments",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="company_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="comment_id"))
private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<>();
```

---

Or we can use `@Formula` annotation.

```
@Formula(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM companies_comments cc WHERE cc.company_id = id)
private int numberOfComments;
```

---

**Edit after 8 months:** For simplicity and performance perspective, we should create a JPA Query Method like below.

```
@Repository
public interface CommentRepository extends JpaRepository<Comment, Long> {

    int countAllByCompany(Company company);
}
```

We should never use `getComments().size()` for this purpose, because this way all comments are loaded into memory and this may be cause performance issues.

It is also true when adding comments to the collection. We shouldn't use `getComments().add(newComment)`. When we have `OneToMany` relation, all we have to do is set the company field of the comment like as `newComment.setCompany(company)`, and perform the persist operation. Therefore, it is recommended to define `OneToMany` relationships bidirectional.

Comment: Both your answer uses proprietary extensions of hibernate, but I guess it was your original intention. Please note the second one is written in native SQL, with the same hiccups of using a native query in case of entity modifications.

Comment: Yes second one is written in native SQL, thanks for addition :)

Answer (score 0):

You should drop the own method counter and create a specific (business) query to retrieve the size of the list, such as

```
public long getCommentsCount(Company c) {
    String query = "SELECT COUNT(cm) FROM Company AS c JOIN c.comments AS cm WHERE c = :company";
    return entityManager.createQuery(q, Long.class).setParameter("company", c).getSingleResult();
}
```

Some persistence provider may optimize performance when this kind of query is loaded as a @NamedQuery on entity, or when using CriteriaQuery API. 
Depending on your database, you may need to change the return class to Number.class and convert to long.

If you want to tune even more your performance, use createNativeQuery method and write your own pure SQL, but keep in mind that changes on db schema requires to review theses queries.